# How to chain two promises with Ajax calls and combine the results?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code:

```
loadData: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url: url1}).done(function(r) { resolve(r); });               
    });
},

drawGraph: function(stats) {
    // do stuff with the stats
},

// lower down...
this.loadData().then(this.drawGraph);
```

It works fine. But now I want to make another Ajax call and combine data the two results, before calling `drawGraph`.

This is what I've tried:

```
loadSiteTraffic: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url: url1}).done(function(r) { resolve(r); });                
    }).then(function(results1) {
        return $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url: url2}).done(function(r) { resolve(r); });
    }).then(function(results1, results2) {
        return results1 + results2;
    });
}
```

But now I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: resolve is not defined` on the second time that `resolve` appears.

I guess this is something about how I pass `resolve` to the second call. 
But I want to hang on to the results of the first call. What should I be doing instead?

Maybe I need to make two separate `loadData` functions, call one from the other, and somehow combine the results in a third function...?

Comment: You can use Promise.all(iterable) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're currently doing is an overkill. You don't need the the Promise constructor wrapper over `$.ajax` call (unless you're doing some complex async operations underneath), as `$.ajax` already exposes promise-like `then` handlers.

Additionally, both of your calls don't depend on each other. So you can simultaneously make both the calls and combine the results using [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
loadSiteTraffic: function() {
    return $.when({
      result1: $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url: url1}),
      result2: $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url: url2})
    })
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.result1 + resp.result2;
    });
}
```

In your code, you encounter the undefined `resolve` as it is not available to the `then` callback.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising - the only problem is that `resp.results1` is now an Ajax response object rather than my data - I can see the data I need inside `responseText` but it looks like raw text. I've tried `resp.results1.responseJSON` but it gives me an unreadable `Object` as a result.

Comment: @Richard -- I'm not sure what you're encountering. First, I'm using `resp.result1`, and not `resp.results1`. Second, `resp.result1` should return whatever data is returned by the server; it is same as what `drawGraph` receives in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do my ajax calls like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: url1,
    success: function (res1) {
       // Do stuff with res1
       $.ajax({ 
          dataType: 'json', 
          url: url2,
          success: function (res2) {
             // Do stuff with res2
             return res1 + res2;
          ),
       });
    ),
});
```

This way the calls are "waiting" for each other to finish.

Comment: I think you should read this http://callbackhell.com/ . It will help you understand why you should improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic method that wrap the ajax call and returns promise:

```js
load: function(param) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax(param).done(function(r) { resolve(r); });          
    });
},

loadData: function() {
    var res1;
    return this.load({ dataType: 'json', url: url1}).then(function(results1) {
        res1 = results1;
        return this.load({ dataType: 'json', url: url2});
    }).then(function(res2) {
        return res1 + res2;
    });
},

drawGraph: function(stats) {
    // do stuff with the stats
},

// lower down...
this.loadData().then(this.drawGraph);
```

If the second call doesn't depends on the first call, you can use promise.all:

```js
load: function(param) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax(param).done(function(r) { resolve(r); });          
  });
},

loadData: function() {
    return Promise.all([
        this.load({ dataType: 'json', url: url1}),
        this.load({ dataType: 'json', url: url2}),
    ]).then(function([results1, results2]) {
        return results1 + results2;
    });
},

drawGraph: function(stats) {
    // do stuff with the stats
},

// lower down...
this.loadData().then(this.drawGraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a general function that makes a promise from your AJAX calls:

```
const ajaxPromise = url => 
 new Promise(resolve => 
        $.ajax({ dataType: 'json', url}).done(r => resolve(r); );               
    );
```

Now, you can either just invoke both of them:

```
Promise.all(ajaxPromise(url1),
            ajaxPromise(url2))
  .then([results1, results2]) => results1 + results2);
```

or if you really need them chained:

```
ajaxPromise(url1)
  .then(results1 =>
     ajaxPromise(url2)
      .then(results2 => results1 + results2));
```